# установка iRedMail без интернета

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, установка

Нужно установить iRedMail на виртуалку Debian/Ubuntu. Есть скачанный архив, но при установке оно докачивает еще файлы из интернета. Как можно этого избежать? У меня на одной машине уже установлен iRedMail по-нормальному с интернетом, может быть можно взять оттуда докачанные файлы и сам архив и кинуть на пустую машину, чтобы на ней установить? Тогда где лежат все докачиваемые файлы?

Comment: Ну, учитывая, что настройка - это sh скрипт - то наверное надо посмотреть куда он что качает и вытащить это руками, а потом на другой машине положить в нужные места.

Comment: как можно это посмотреть?

Comment: Открываешь каждый sh скрипт блокнотом\любимой ide и смотришь глазами.

Comment: Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, учитывая, что настройка - это `sh` скрипт - то наверное надо посмотреть куда он что качает и вытащить это руками, а потом на другой машине положить в нужные места.
Блокнот в помощь.